# Why was the "bread communication" in the arena of Catching Fire left out in the movie?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-hunger-games, catching-fire

In the book, Katniss and her partners received several pieces of bread during the course of the game. The amount and type of bread serves as a countdown for a start of the rebellion.

Bread seemed so innocent, yet was used to communicate between mentor and tribute for the start of a rebellion in the 75th Hunger Games.

This was a significant detail in the book, so why did they chose to leave it out in the movie?

Comment: why waste time on boring moss colored bread props when u have a 130M budget and can do poisonous fog & vamp monkeys?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Books and movies are fundamentally different media, and require different storytelling techniques

Movies are better at conveying some things, like action or background events, but much worse at conveying other details, such as private character thoughts and expository details.

Also, movies have much less space for content than books do.  Your average 100k word book does not fit in a 2 hour movie without significant trimming.  Some things have to be cut.

**The bread communication was intrinsically difficult to portray**
The whole point of the bread was that the characters were not free to speak openly.  That means that we would need some kind of internal monologue in order to explain the significance of the bread.  An internal monologue or narration isn't something you can just add for one detail - you'd need to use it throughout the story, and it would significantly change the feel of the movie.

Something had to be cut for space reasons, so they chose this detail that was ill-suited for the screen as one of the cut items.

Comment: "An internal monologue or narration isn't something you can just add for one detail - you'd need to use it throughout the story, and it would significantly change the feel of the movie." Case in point: David Lynch's *Dune*. There's a reason that it's so rarely done in film.

Comment: @Thunderforge Overall, this was the biggest difference between the books and the films in this case.  The books spend so much time inside Katniss' head and all of that had to be left out of the movies because they didn't want use a voiceover narration.  It had the unfortunate side-effect of making her performance seem a bit stiff and emotionless, but this is actually book-accurate because she _had_ to conceal her emotions for the sake of the games.  It just doesn't translate very well to film.

Comment: I agree that books and movies are different, a book can exploit so much more details than a movie but in this case, if I remember well, the amount and type of bread was explained by Beetee after they got out of the arena. So that's why I wondered why they didn't translated it to the movie.

Comment: @Panchoa I think that this answer is correct, but in this specific case there's also another factor. The point of the bread signals (plot-wise) is that they're extremely difficult to notice. For something to matter in a movie, it needs to be noticed by the audience (or at least be notice-able). It would be a challenge to make the bread, and its importance, clear to the audience throughout the story while also having it be subtle enough to be effective within the story. Perhaps it *could* be done, but it might be very challenging to do so and not worth the effort of the people making the movie.

Comment: @Upper_Case But they have a 130M budget!!! IMO they should've done it.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I'm usually of the opinion that movies should be as faithful to the books they're based on as possible, but sometimes that does make for a worse movie. If "doing it" in this case meant the movie took 6 months longer to release, and ruined a bunch of effective shots to highlight bread quantity, and required otherwise irrelevant scenes and sequences only to highlight that single plot point, it's possible that (given the option of different cuts) you would prefer the slightly less faithful one. I love *GoT*, but a perfectly faithful adaptation would be difficult to watch.

Comment: @Upper_Case To each there own. I personally enjoy picking holes in every film I watch, much to the irritation of family members.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Sounds like you prefer movies to have those holes to pick! I'm the same way, really (my girlfriend made the innocent mistake of watching SciFi Channel's *A Wizard of Earthsea* with me, which is nonstop mistakes that materially alter the plot. I think there were maybe 5 minutes total where I wasn't complaining). But I, personally, don't think *CF* would be better with a heavy bread-counting subplot, in the same way I don't think *Star Wars* would be better without blaster sounds in spaceship combat. More accurate, yes, but more fun, no.

Comment: @Upper_Case The whole point of hole picking is that you pick holes! I'm not complaining about the movie, it's great.

Comment: "Your average 100k book does not fit in a 2 hour movie without significant trimming." Or there's the Hobbit strategy of releasing it as three movies. And did you intend to have "words" between "100k" and "book"?

Comment: @Acccumulation, no, I was only missing a single word.   :D

Comment: I agree with @ArtemisFowl they could have done itwith this budget, but i also agree with the explanation of Upper_Case. So I checked this answer as correct.